# Change the URL header when redirection from the Authentication Framework?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am using Identity Server 5.0.0 version of wso2.please consider that I am using a proxy server. From my client app while I trying to work on SSO, application server is redirecting to Identity Server, to an URL with the IP mentioned in carbon.xml for hostname element in carbon.xml with the context root as commonauth and default port number as 9443, irrespective of the SAML Identity Provider URL provided. We do not want to redirect to IP from hostname.carbon.xml and 9443 for commonauth context redirection.

Ex: when application redirected to Identity Server, it should redirect to https://192.168.23.18:9443/samlsso; 
whereas before redirecting to this URL another redirection with commonauth context root and port number 9443 is happening with the IP mentioned in carbon.xml, as https://100.64.122.212:9443/commonauth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All what you have to do is change the redirected URL location header to the `[https://192.168.23.18:9443/]`. You can follow the guidelines to achieve your requirement.

Find following valid blog of one of the WSO2 team member.[1]

[1] http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/11/16/how-to-developing-identity-server-behind-proxy-or-load-balancer/